# What do "schema" and "meta symbol" mean in F# expressions?

Tags: f#

I'm working through a [textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107684064) on F# and after introducing the factorial function

```
let rec fact = function | 0 -> 1 | n-> n * fact(n-1);;
```

the authors also point out that the evaluation of an expression containing `fact` might not terminate and add in a [footnote](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6qtTR9xURVIC&pg=PA10&lpg=PA10&dq=%22f#%22%20schema%20meta%20symbol&source=bl&ots=E5ZwAcDvIW&sig=wuHEivyPGL1MFanDfXh5l8j90uM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zVgnUsDQNImP0AWoo4D4Ag&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22f#%22%20schema%20meta%20symbol&f=false)

> Note that a text like `fact` *n* is *not* part of F#. It is a *schema* where one can obtain a program piece by replacing the *meta symbol n* with a suitable F# entity.

This has gone right over my head! Although I'm happy with how `fact` works, and with recursion in other languages, I can't see the distinction the authors are trying to make here. Any explanations welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect all they're trying to say is `n` represents a value (i.e., "F# entity") being passed to the function. `fact n` is not meant to be valid F# code.

It's legalese for "`n` is a *placeholder*."